# Can Rook pawn still get win when opponent clock run out?

Tags: rules, draw

White has Rook pawn and King vs Black king just jumping from corner and back. But the game played on clock and black king clock run out. White avoided threefold and stalemate and moved his king to just let opponents clock run out. Does white get the win even though this is a draw in a game played without a clock?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The player whose opponent's time ran out wins if there exists a way to win. A draw only happens, when White couldn't even win with help from his opponent, e.g. when there is insufficient material.

Law 6.9 of the [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/LawsOfChess.pdf) states:

> Except where one of the Articles: 5.1.a, 5.1.b, 5.2.a, 5.2.b, 5.2.c applies, if a player does not complete the prescribed number of moves in the allotted time, the game is lost by the player. However, the game is drawn, if the position is such that **the opponent cannot checkmate the player’s king by any possible series of legal moves**.

However, it is not allowed to win such positions by only trying to flag the opponent. If a player with less than 2 min on his clock notices his opponent is only trying to flag, according to article 10.2 a)

> If the arbiter agrees the opponent is making no effort to win the game by normal means, or that it is not possible to win by normal means, then he shall declare the game drawn. Otherwise he shall postpone his decision or reject the claim.